# How to group factors by product and display if a product has more than one factor-pair?

Tags: php, grouping, element, multiplication, factors

Using a predefined array of numbers, how can I use PHP to generate a multi-dimensional array which groups all factor-pairs by their product?

Input array:

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
```

- I want to display all factor-pairs for each product group that have more than one factor-pair.
- In a case where there are no product groups that have more than one factor-pair, `No pairs Found` should be displayed.

Given the above input, this is my expected result:

```
1 6 and 2 3  // product group = 6
1 8 and 2 4  // product group = 8
2 6 and 3 4  // product group = 12
3 8 and 4 6  // product group = 24
```

*note as the input array increases in size, the output will display more than two factor-pairs per group.

This is my code from C++:

```
 void findPairs(int arr[], int n)
{
    bool found = false;
    unordered_map<int, pair < int, int > > H;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (int j=i+1; j<n; j++)
        {
            // If product of pair is not in hash table,
            // then store it
            int prod = arr[i]*arr[j];
            if (H.find(prod) == H.end())
                H[prod] = make_pair(i,j);

            // If product of pair is also available in
            // then print current and previous pair
            else
            {
                pair<int,int> pp = H[prod];
                cout << arr[pp.first] << " " << arr[pp.second]
                     << " and " << arr[i]<<" "<<arr[j]<<endl;
                found = true;
            }
        }
    }
    // If no pair find then print not found
    if (found == false)
        cout << "No pairs Found" << endl;
}
```

Comment: and what is the logic behind it ?

Comment: i can do the same in c++ but not in php

Comment: I agree, but what's logic behind the output means how you are getting output ? Or rather, can you post your c++ code here

Comment: like 1*6 = 2*3 = 6  as ab= cd

Comment: Post some code. Even the C++ code could help.

Comment: @axiac i posted the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your C++ code "translated" to PHP (mostly by search & replace).

90% of the translation was achieved by removing the variable types and prepending the variable names with `$`. The [`array`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) PHP type is a mixture of array, list and map (aka hash, dictionary) and can be used for both `$H` and the values it contains (pairs of values).

```
function findPairs(array $arr, $n)
{
    $found = false;
    $H = array();
    for ($i=0; $i<$n; $i++)
    {
        for ($j=$i+1; $j<$n; $j++)
        {
            // If product of pair is not in hash table,
            // then store it
            $prod = $arr[$i]*$arr[$j];
            if (! array_key_exists($prod, $H))
                $H[$prod] = array($i,$j);

            // If product of pair is also available in
            // then print current and previous pair
            else
            {
                $pp = $H[$prod];
                echo $arr[$pp[0]], " ", $arr[$pp[1]]
                     , " and ", $arr[$i], " ", $arr[$j], "\n";
                $found = true;
            }
        }
    }
    // If no pair find then print not found
    if ($found == false)
        echo "No pairs Found\n";
}

$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
findPairs($array, count($array));
```

And this is its output:

```
1 6 and 2 3
1 8 and 2 4
2 6 and 3 4
3 8 and 4 6
```

Comment: Thanks @axiac for best answer

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution will work fine with a small array like your example but will use a lot of memory for bigger inputs. Basically, first calculate all products by using a nested loop. For every product, create a list of inputs that generate the product. Mind you that there might be more than 2 ways to get a certain result, so you might get an output like `1 12 and 2 6 and 3 4` for bigger lists.

For an input of size N, you need to store ((N -1) * N) / 2 tuples in memory, so that's something to keep in mind.

```
$input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

$products = [];

foreach ($input as $index1 => $value1) {
    // Assuming you only want unique combinations, only combine this value with the other values coming after it
    for ($index2 = $index1 + 1; $index2 < count($input); $index2++) {
        $value2 = $input[$index2];
        $product = $value1 * $value2;

        // Make sure there is an entry in the $products array for adding this input to
        if (!isset($products[$product])) {
            $products[$product] = [];
        }

        // Add this input (formatted) to the list of possible inputs resulting in this product
        $products[$product][] = sprintf('%d %d', $value1, $value2);
    }
}

// Print all inputs resulting in the same products, if there are more than 1 way to produce the same output
foreach ($products as $inputs) {
    if (count($inputs) > 1) {
        echo implode(' and ', $inputs), PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Will output

```
1 6 and 2 3
1 8 and 2 4
2 6 and 3 4
3 8 and 4 6
```

Answer (score 1):

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/764216)

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
$result=array();
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
$counter=0;
$noOfPairs=3;
while (count($result)!=$noOfPairs)
{
    shuffle($array);
    getPair($array);
}
print_r($result);
function getPair($array)
{
    global $result;
    $product=$array[0]*$array[1];
    if(isset($result[$product]))
    {
        return false;
    }
    $result[$product][]=array($array[0],$array[1]);
    unset($array[0]);
    unset($array[1]);
    foreach($array as $key1 => $value1)
    {
        foreach($array as $key2 => $value2)
        {
            if($value1*$value2==$product)
            {
                $result[$product][]=array($value1,$value2);
                break;
            }
        }
         if(count($result[$product])==2)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if(count($result[$product])==1)
    {
        unset($result[$product]);
    }
}
```

Comment: why u use $noOfPairs; the condition like pair ab=cd

Comment: I have added this `$noOfPairs` to prevent unnecessary looping. Lets say if you want to create 4 combination just make it `$noOfPairs=4;`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't speed test my method but I think it is more direct and easier to read.
Basically, it generates the full multi-dim array, then filters out any subarrays that have only one pair, then if there are subarrays remaining, it displays them.  Simple.

My method performs without any `count()` calls and without incrementing key variables.  It uses the very fast `isset()` call to filter the result array and `array_walk()` to iterate and `implode()` the qualifying subarrays.

As a bonus feature, I've used `range()` to dynamically generate the input array which is determined by entering the highest value for the array.  Of course, if you want to find pairs for `[3,4,5]`, then you'll have to modify this process or simply revert to your original style -- it depends on your project expectations.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c3b73295efde51987f6202d8bcc11780fcc0ad68))

```
function findPairs($maxfactor){
    $array=range(1,$maxfactor); // spare yourself having to write out the array
    foreach($array as $v1){
        $array=array_slice($array,1); // shrink array as you go to avoid needless iterations
        foreach($array as $v2){
            $result[$v1*$v2][]="$v1 $v2";  // generate multi-dim output array using products as outer keys
        }
    }
    $result=array_filter($result,function($a){return isset($a[1]);});  // remove elements with < 2 pairs
    if(!$result){
        echo "No pairs found";
    }else{
        array_walk($result,function($a){echo implode(' and ',$a),"\n";});
    }
}
findPairs(8);
```

Output:

```
1 6 and 2 3
1 8 and 2 4
2 6 and 3 4
3 8 and 4 6
```